# pass user arg to DESeq2 function

Tags: r, arguments, string-parsing, bioconductor, optparse

I'm trying to run `DESeq` in an RScript using parameters input from the command line. I used `optparse` to parse user arguments and am trying to pass the design argument into the `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix()` function.

I tested the function directly and it works perfectly:

```
DESeq_tbl <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=counts_tbl,
colData=coldata, design=~taxonomy)
```

However, if I try to pass the variable `opt$design` (which is a character string = "~taxonomy"), I get the following error:

```
DESeq_tbl <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=counts_tbl,
colData=coldata, design=opt$design)
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors Execution halted

I've tried `noquote()`, various combinations of `cat`/`paste` and creating the entire command as a string to pass to the `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix()` function, but nothing has worked. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

### the solution

Thanks to Ben Bolker's answer below, the following worked:

```
DESeq_tbl <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=counts_tbl,
colData=coldata, design=as.formula(opt$design))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need `as.formula(opt$design)`.

```
x <- "~taxonomy"
f <- ~taxonomy
str(f)
## Class 'formula'  language ~taxonomy
## ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
identical(f,as.formula(x)) ## TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not heard of that method; you just saved my weekend :)

Comment: I didn't know tilde (~) needs to be part of the formula. I did ```~as.formula("taxonomy")```